# How to navigate between different nested stacks in react navigation - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I have been using createStackNavigator to be able to navigator throughout my app.

I have created a number of different stacks. Within each stack I have my header code. I have a button in each header that I want to be able to press in order to navigate to another screen, however this screen is within another stack. How would I get access to it?

Here is my code.

```js
export const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
  Search: {
    screen: SearchScreen
         });


export const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home:
  {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          headerTitle: 'Home',
           headerRight: (
             <Icon name="ios-search" color="#fff" size={30} style={{paddingRight: 20}}
             onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SearchStack', {}, NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Search'}))} />
            ),
             headerTitleStyle:{
               color: "white",
               alignSelf: "center",
               fontSize: 20        
             }, 
             headerStyle:{
               backgroundColor: "#404042"
            } 
          }),
      },
  Listen: {
    screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          headerTitle: 'Listen',
           headerRight: (
             <Icon name="ios-search" color="#fff" size={30} style={{paddingRight: 20}}
             onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Search')} />
             ),
             headerTitleStyle:{
               color: "white",
               alignSelf: "center",
               fontSize: 20        
             },
             headerStyle:{
               backgroundColor: "#404042"
            } 
           }
          },
       
         },                             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can call any screen you want as long it is in one of the stacks.